# Strange results when multiplying 3 by 1.1

Tags: javascript, floating-point, multiplication

When I multiply `3 * 1.1` in JavaScript instead of returning `3.3`, it results in `3.30000000000000003`, Why is this?

Comment: [relevante](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999#comic)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Currently, we only support English, so would you be so kind to translate your question?

Comment: This is because js stores numbers as floating point values and floating points arithmetics aren't always 100 % accurate. 0.2 + 0.1 for example does not give 0.3 in javascript but 0.30000000000000004

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Do you have any more constructive question than "Why is this?"

Answer (score 2):

That's because numbers in computers are represented as [floating point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/), which have limited precision. Some operations will cause tiny errors and there's nothing you can do about that.

It's also a reason to never compare numbers using `==`.

Comment: Thanks @cpacheco for translating into Spanish.

Comment: So if we should not compare it by `==` , then what is the recommended way?

Comment: @AyushKumar compare them to some tolerance: `a == b` becomes `Math.abs(a - b) < TOLERANCE`. What that tolerance is depends on context. Note that JS has the concept of "safe integers", which IIRC are up to [2^53](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), so if you're only doing additions, subtractions, multiplications, or divisions of even integers, by integers, that result in values in that range, you can be sure they're the same and you can use `==`.